# how to run a python virtual environment on termux

Tags: python

**I am trying to use a virtual environment on android.** using `virtualenv env1` **command** but I am getting the following error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not
permitted:'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3' -> 
'/storage/emulated/0/@tsmile/projects/env1/bin/python'
```

Comment: Try changing permissions of the file you are trying to execute.

Comment: Or try running with sudo access

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can not run in  .

`"/Storage/emulated/0/....."`

It can only be run in termux Home directory .

For creating it :

1. `cd ~`
2. `virtualenv newenv`.
3. `source newenv/bin/activate` .

Now venv is created in
`/data/data/com.termux/files/home`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The limitation seems to be that Android doesn't allow creating symbolic links on the ‘shared’ storage (i.e. on the ‘sdcard’, outside of the app data directory)—while `virtualenv` and the `venv` module both use symlinks.

Answer (score 1):

**termux-setup-storage grants Termux storage permission**
*Run 'termux-setup-storage' command, and grant it storage permission by following information on the pop up window, that appears when you run the command.
Cd into '/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/shared and start creating your stuffs.
Now termux have full access your storage and you won't experience PermissionError while creating your virtual environment in this directory
You can still create you virtual without granting termux storage permission, but only in this directory: 'data/data/com.termux/files/home'.

When you create your stuffs in this directory you may not be able to access the files with text editors and/or file managers, which you will occasionally need to.

Comment: Hi Isaac, thank you for your time and contribution. I appreciate if you could enhance the content structure of your solution. Consider using bullets and code blocks to improve readability. Currently, it is challenging to follow your answer and text.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.
Open 'termux' app, then virtualenv env1

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: If you repeatedly vandalize your post a moderator will get involved and lock the post.